# Callback function is not working as expected in watefall on async.foreachlimit

Tags: node.js, for-loop, asynchronous, waterfall

The callback function is not working as expected in a waterfall on async.for each limit. 
When I remove that rest api call and if I call `callback(null,arg2)` it is working as expected, I think the problem with callback function or some api call in the below code.

```js
var async = require("async");
var users = [1, 2, 3, 45]; // Initialize user array or get it from DB
var e = [];
var unirest = require("unirest");
var data = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    async.forEachLimit(
      users,
      1,
      function(user, userCallback) {
        async.waterfall(
          [
            function(callback) {
              console.log(user);
              callback(null, user);
            },
            function(arg1, callback) {
              console.log(arg1);
              callback(null, arg1);
            },
            function(arg2, callback) {
              unirest
                .get("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/1")
                .end(function(response) {
                  if (response.error) callback("null", "data");
                  else callback(null, arg2);
                });
            }
          ],
          function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
              console.log("err");
              reject(e);
            } else {
              console.log("done", result);
              e.push(result);
              userCallback();
              resolve(e);
            }
          }
        );
      },
      function(err, result) {
        console.log("User For Loop Completed", err, result);
      }
    );
  });
};
```

I'm getting output as

[image]

expected outputs as

[image]